# NextJs - Compute base for Link href based on folder structure

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, nextjs-dynamic-routing, react-server-components

I'm creating an app using the [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating) pattern in Nextjs.

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

[image: folder-structure]

From inside the `level-1` page, I would like to link to `level-1/level-2`.

Obviously I can do this by hardcoding href to `level-1/level-2`. However, is there a way to compute the `level-1` value dynamically, so I could do something like this:

```html
<Link href="/level-2">
    This should automatically link to /level-1/level-2
</Link>
```

I could use [usePathname](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname) - but this would work only on the client side.

Is there a way to accomplish this based only on the code structure somehow ?

Comment: do u want to do it in server component?

Comment: @Yilmaz yes, i want to do it in a server component.

Comment: Can u use the Link component on the server component?

Comment: @Yilmaz Yes you can, Here's the documentation [When to use server component and client component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#when-to-use-server-and-client-components)

Comment: @sarincasm, I've looked it up, this is not a behavior Next expects (relative pathnames - like react-router-dom)...


Why don't you use dynamic routing instead? 


Your project directory will look like:
```Levels/[level].tsx```